# UIDatePicker date ignored when minimum date is set

Tags: ios, ios7, uidatepicker

I only display hours and minutes in my date picker.
I need to restrict the minimum time of my picker and display the current time.

The problem is, when I set the minimum date property AND the date property of my picker, the date property is ignored and automatically set to the minimum date.

For example:
Minimum date set to 10:30 AM
Date set to 11:00 AM

The picker minimum date is restricted to 10:30 AM (it's OK) but it displays 10:30 AM.

Can you help me fixing this problem ?

Thanks a lot in advance !

**EDIT: FIX IT !**

I construct my date picker with a date from components. The problem was I only specified the NSCalendarUnitHour and NSCalendarUnitMinute. When I added the day, month and year, it works !
Thanks to Rose (see the comments below).

Answer (score 2):

Please set datePicker's date like the below code

```
 [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

 [datePicker setMinimumDate:[Your Minimum time]];
```

Comment: I just came to try your code, but it doesn't work. Here is my code:[self.timePicker setDate:[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:componentsNow]]; and [self.timePicker setMinimumDate:arrivalHour];

Comment: what do you get in the pickerview

Comment: My picker dosen't display the date but the minimum date. When I comment the line where I set the minimum date, the picker displays the good time.

Comment: Please check this[datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];

Comment: Oh ! When I set the [NSDate date], it display correctly the current date, It seems that my date from components is not good. In fact, when I construct my date from components, I only specified hour and minute for the component so the date wasn't correct. Thanks a lot for your help !